# WDIO: Request is timed out for Multiremote Sauce-Labs session start

Tags: typescript, automation, webdriver-io, saucelabs

I need to run tests in 2 different browsers simultaneously - 1 Web + 1 Mobile Web.
I am trying to set up wdio to work with Multiremote settings but no luck.
I am getting logs with retries:

```
...
[0-0] 2021-12-30T13:36:26.056Z INFO webdriver: [POST] https://ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:4723/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2021-12-30T13:36:26.056Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
...
```

Then it fails with error:

```
0-0] 2021-12-30T13:37:41.062Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status undefined due to RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT my-ip:4723 when running "https://ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:4723/wd/hub/session" with method "POST" and args "{"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"chrome","browserVersion":"latest","platformName":"macOS 11","sauce:options":{"extendedDebugging":true}},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","browserVersion":"latest","platformName":"macOS 11","sauce:options":{"extendedDebugging":true}}}"
[0-0] 2021-12-30T13:37:41.062Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT my-ip:4723 when running "https://ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:4723/wd/hub/session" with method "POST" and args "{"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"chrome","browserVersion":"latest","platformName":"macOS 11","sauce:options":{"extendedDebugging":true}},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","browserVersion":"latest","platformName":"macOS 11","sauce:options":{"extendedDebugging":true}}}"
[0-0]     at getTimeoutError (/Users/admin/Documents/Work/new-runner/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:295:24)
...
```

My test consists only from me opening an url with `browser.url('url')` command in describe and test blocks.
Whole project is created from zero using `yarn create wdio .` command.

My config file is:

```
export const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
    port: 4723,
    user: "my_user_name",
    key: "my_key",
    region: 'eu',
    specs: [
        './tests/**/*.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    maxInstances: 6,
    capabilities: {
        webBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                browserVersion: 'latest',
                platformName: 'macOS 12',
                'sauce:options': {}
            }
        },
        appBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'Safari',
                'appium:deviceName': 'iPhone 13',
                platformName: 'iOS',
                'appium:platformVersion': '15.0',
                'sauce:options': {},
            }
        }
    },
    logLevel: 'info',
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    services: ['sauce', 'appium', 'selenium-standalone'],
    framework: 'mocha',
    reporters: ['spec'],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },
}
```

I also cannot access my browsers in the test file like it is shown in their guide, e.g. `browser["webBrowser"].url('...')`.

Please help, thank you **very** much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, I found the answer right away after I asked this question :/

The answer is: remove port option, remove appium and selenium-standalone from services.